# Why Android Studio has this @Nullable thing?

Tags: android-studio, annotations, nullable

I am just kind of curious about this weird thing that Android Studio is showing me. I was about to use the `addView` method when this tool-tip-like thingy pops up:

[image]

I am quite confused because of the `@Nullable` annotations on the parameters. `View` can be null because it is a reference type. But why an explicit `@Nullable` annotation?

When I go into the definition of the `addView` method, I see no annotations! Then I am more confused.

So I want to ask why Android Studio has this weird thingy.

Comment: What is your question, are you asking why it is trying to be helpful and tell you what is nullable and what isn't?

Comment: @musefan I just want to ask why is it here but no in the source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `View` can be null because it is a reference type. But why an explicit
>   `@Nullable` annotation?

In technical sense, yes, View is reference thus `null` is one of values. In the same sense, `width` and `height` arguments in one of overloads are of type `int` so technically you could pass `0`, `2147483647` or `-1` value as height, for example, but it probably wouldn't make any sense. The same way, passing `null` as a value, however syntactically valid, may or may not make sense. Some functions throw `NullPointerException` when passed a `null` value. `@Nullable` annotation means that `null` is acceptable value, and function will handle that:

[Nullable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/Nullable.html):

> Denotes that a parameter, field or method return value can be null.
>
> When decorating a method call parameter, this denotes that the
>   parameter can legitimately be null and the method will gracefully deal
>   with it. Typically used on optional parameters.
>
> When decorating a method, this denotes the method might legitimately
>   return null.
>
> This is a marker annotation and it has no specific attributes.